# SQL Multiple NOT LIKE with possible NULL values

Tags: mysql, null, sql-like

I am trying to pull data where multiple fields that are not like '%1%', '%2%', and '%3%

However, one or more of these fields are prone to be NULL, which is causing them to be neglected in the results. I want the results with NULL values as well. I am seeing  instances where data1 = 5, data2 = 6, and data3 is NULL and those records are not being returned.

Here is my query:

```
WHERE
region = 'AZ' and
year(date) = '2014' and

data1 not like '%1%' and
data2 not like '%1%' and
data3 not like '%1%' and

data1 not like '%2%' and
data2 not like '%2%' and
data3 not like '%2%' and

data1 not like '%3%' and
data2 not like '%3%' and
data3 not like '%3%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around. I opened a test table, converted all the NULL values to '0', then ran my query. It looks something like this:

```
Drop table #test
Select
region
, data1
, data2
, data3
into #test

from YourTable

Where
region = 'AZ' and
year(date) = '2014' and
data1 is NULL or 

region = 'AZ' and
year(date) = '2014' and
data2 is NULL or 

region = 'AZ' and
year(date) = '2014' and
data3 is NULL or

--------

UPDATE [#test] SET [data1] = 0 WHERE [data1] IS NULL
UPDATE [#test] SET [data2] = 0 WHERE [data2] IS NULL
UPDATE [#test] SET [data3] = 0 WHERE [data3] IS NULL

--------

Select
region
, data1
, data2
, data3

from #test

Where
data1 not like '%1%' and
data2 not like '%1%' and
data3 not like '%1%' and

data1 not like '%2%' and
data2 not like '%2%' and
data3 not like '%2%' and

data1 not like '%3%' and
data2 not like '%3%' and
data3 not like '%3%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an OR clause at the end

```
WHERE
region = 'AZ' and
year(date) = '2014' and
(
data1 not like '%1%' and
data2 not like '%1%' and
data3 not like '%1%' and

data1 not like '%2%' and
data2 not like '%2%' and
data3 not like '%2%' and

data1 not like '%3%' and
data2 not like '%3%' and
data3 not like '%3%'
OR data1 IS NULL OR data2 IS NULL OR data3 IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Hi Minh, thank you for your response. When I add those changes you specify above I still get unwanted results. I should specify further. I want the query to return results that do not have 1, 2, or 3 in data1, data2, or data3. However, if one of those elements is NULL then I do want that included in the results. When I add your changes I get all results where data1 is NULL, including results where data1 is NULL and data2 = 1, which I do not want. Any idea how to avoid those results while also including NULL values? Thank you.